# flutter - create stack from a list

Tags: flutter

I'm tring to acheive this:

[image]

I am tring to do this using a stack (so that part of one image is above another. see picture). nothing appear on screen and not errors. What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need `ListView` to achieve it.
Instead you put all child widgets into `Stack` and wrap them into `Positioned` widget, which will allow you to control their position.

Example code:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final avatars = <Widget>[];
  final avatarWidth = 40;
  final overlayWidth = 10;
  for(int i = 0; i < attendingImagesList.length; i++) {
    avatars.add(
      Positioned(
        left: (avatarWidth - overlayWidth)*i,
        child: // put image widget here,   
      )
    );
  }

  return Stack(children: avatars);
}
```

Comment: I didn't know i  can you for! thanks, but It still doesn't works. I will edit my question

Comment: never mind. the issue is something else (Invalid argument(s): No host specified in URI file://..) I will try to solve this now